# Derived subsets and topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, gre-exam

My question is regarding question $56$ from [this GRE practice exam](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~cmarshak/GRE2.pdf) [PDF]:

> For a subset $S$ of a topological space $X$, let $\operatorname{cl}(S)$ denote the closure of $S$ in $X$, and let $S'=\{x:x\in\operatorname{cl}(S\setminus\{x\})\}$ denote the derived set of $S$. If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$, which of the following statements are true?
>
> 1. $(A\cup B)'=A'\cup B'$
> 2. $(A\cap B)'=A'\cap B'$
> 3. If $A'$ is empty, then $A$ is closed in $X$.
> 4. If $A$ is open in $X$, then $A'$ is not empty.
>
> (A) $(1)$ and $(2)$ only
>   (B) $(1)$ and $(3)$ only
>   (C) $(2)$ and $(4)$ only
>   (D) $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ only
>   (E) $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$, and $(4)$

Intuitively I visualize the derived set $S'$ as the boundary of a set, although this seems insufficient. I am wondering if there is a good reference for a quick exposition of derived subsets. It would be great if the response can include a geometric description or understanding of $S'$ since this is how I usually like to see things in my head.

Comment: My original answer, now deleted, was based on a slightly different definition of *derived set*.

Answer (score 2):

**Corrected to use the right definition of *derived set*.**

The points of $S$ that are *not* in $S'$ are precisely the isolated points of $S$, i.e., the points $x\in S$ such that $\{x\}$ is a relatively open subset of $S$. In addition, $S'$ contains every limit point of $S$ that is not already in $S$. Thus, $S'$ consists of those points of $\operatorname{cl}S$ that are not isolated points in $\operatorname{cl}S$.

Thus, if $S'=\varnothing$, every point of $\operatorname{cl}S$ is isolated in $\operatorname{cl}S$, and $\operatorname{cl}S$ therefore has the discrete topology as a subset of $X$. But then $\operatorname{cl}S=S$ (why?), so $S$ is closed. This settles $(3)$: $(3)$ is true.

To settle $(4)$ we can use the often useful approach of looking at extreme cases: what if $A=\varnothing$? Then $A$ is certainly open, but $A'$ is by definition a subset of $A$, so $A'=\varnothing$, and we see that $(4)$ need not be true. If you want a more substantial example, take $X$ to be $\Bbb Z$ with the discrete topology, and let $A$ be any subset of $X$: $A$ is certainly open in $X$, but $A'=\varnothing$.

At this point you know that the only possible answers are (B) and (D), so $(1)$ is presumably true. If you have time later, you can come back and prove it.

**Proof of $\mathbf{(1)}$:**

> Suppose that $x\in A'$. Then $$\begin{align*}x&\in\operatorname{cl}(A\setminus\{x\})\\&\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(A\setminus\{x\})\cup\operatorname{cl}(B\setminus\{x\})\\&=\operatorname{cl}\big((A\setminus\{x\})\cup(B\setminus\{x\})\big)\\&=\operatorname{cl}\big((A\cup B)\setminus\{x\}\big)\;,\end{align*}$$ so by definition $x\in(A\cup B)'$. Thus, $A'\subseteq(A\cup B)'$, and by symmetry $B'\subseteq(A\cup B)'$, so $A'\cup B'\subseteq(A\cup B)'$.
>
> Now suppose that $x\in(A\cup B)'$. Then, making use of the previous calculations to skip a few steps, we have $$\begin{align*}x&\in\operatorname{cl}\big((A\cup B)\setminus\{x\}\big)\\&=\operatorname{cl}(A\setminus\{x\})\cup\operatorname{cl}(B\setminus\{x\})\end{align*}$$ and hence $x\in\operatorname{cl}(A\setminus\{x\})$ or $x\in\operatorname{cl}(B\setminus\{x\})$. But then $x\in A'$ or $x\in B'$, so $(A\cup B)'\subseteq A'\cup B'$. Combining results, we see that $(1)$ holds.

To choose between (B) and (D), we must see whether $(2)$ is necessarily true. And in fact it’s not: take $A=[0,1)$ and $B=(1,2]$ with $X=\Bbb R$. Then $(A\cap B)'=\varnothing$, but $A'\cap B'=[0,1]\cap[1,2]=\{1\}$. Thus, the correct answer is (B).

Comment: In your example, $A' = \{0\}$, not $\varnothing$, isn't it?

Comment: Isn't $X=\Bbb R$, $A=(-\infty,0)$ and $B=(0, \infty)$ a counter-example for property (2).?

Comment: @PeterFranek I agree. Good one.

Comment: (3) can be proved to be correct. Since by definition, $A$ is closed if and only if $A' \subset A$. Since $\varnothing$ is subset of any set, $A$ is closed if $A' = \varnothing$.

Comment: I used the definition of Rudin's textbook. I understand that different authors may have different definitions.

Answer (score 2):

(4) is not correct, the discrete topology is a counter-example. (2) seems also not right, because for $X=\mathbb{R}$, $A=(-\infty,0)$ and $B=(0,\infty)$, $(A\cap B)'=\emptyset\neq A'\cap B'.$ This excludes all answers except (B).